# How to change my add to cart button to increment and decrement button according to product unit quantity in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How to change my add to cart button to increment and decrement button according to product unit quantity according to ion-select drop down menu in ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

```
templateUrl: ‘build/pages/titlepage/titlepage.html’,})
export class titlePage 
{
    qty:any;
    constructor(private nav: NavController) 
    {
        this.qty = 1;
    }
    `enter code here`

// increment product qty
incrementQty()
{
    console.log(this.qty+1);
    this.qty += 1;
}

// decrement product qty
decrementQty() 
{
    if(this.qty-1 < 1 )
    {
        this.qty = 1
        console.log(‘1->’+this.qty);
    }
else{
    this.qty -= 1;
    console.log(‘2->’+this.qty);
    }
}
}

this for .ts file
```